# how to do another show action in a show.html.erb in a 2 nested model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - `Task` and `Project`.

Now I have already nested my task under projects and I can create a new task inside the `views/project/show.html.erb`.

Now what I want to do is to do another show action inside of it

> `<tbody>
>       <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
>         <tr>
>           <td><%= task.name %></td>
>           <td><%= task.description %></td>
>            <td><%= link_to 'Show', project_task_path(@task,:project_id) %></td>
>         </tr>
>
>       <% end %>
>     </tbody>`

```
  class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_project
  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
     @tasks = Task.where(project_id: @project.id)
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.project_id = @project.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you give a little more details. What for?

Comment: So, essentially you want to show the Project that is related to the Task? If that's the case, then the Show method should be on a projects_controller. Showing projects is not the concern of the tasks_controller.

Comment: @MïchaelMakaröv what i want to do is this is  i want to make project and under that project i want to make tasks and view that under the project/show now heres were i have the hard time, in the project/show i want an action that would allow me to redirect to a specific task/show samething with what you do in the project/index

project ->show->(nested)tasks->(action)to go to a specific task

Comment: @MïchaelMakaröv
i get this error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>"project_id", :project_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_id]

Comment: @ccai what iwant to do is to have a show action for task inside the project show where the project show has rendered the index view of  task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be best looking at [*partials*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> Partial templates - usually just called "partials" - are another device for breaking the rendering process into more manageable chunks. With a partial, you can move the code for rendering a particular piece of a response to its own file.

In your case, you'll be able to populate a partial with the relevant tasks for your project:

```
#app/views/projects/show.html.erb
<table>
   <%= render @project.tasks %>
</table>

#app/views/projects/_task.html.erb
<tr>
   <td><%= task.name %></td>
   <td><%= task.decription %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', project_task_path(task,@project) %></td>
</tr>
```

From what I understand, this should answer your question...?

Comment: nope i still get errors

ithink the problems is in the controllers somewhat im missing some conditions of a sort sorry im just new to this language